# GlobalLayoutLIstener behavior for Fragment?

Tags: android, layout, fragment

I am using GlobalLayoutLIstener  in an fragment that is associate with an Activity, and this activity has other associative fragment as well, what I am observing is global layout listener calling for every fragment, even I didn't set it in those fragment.

any one have idea how to use GlobalLayoutLIstener using single context in different-2 fragment?